# KOMA-script: enddot with appendix

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, appendices

Using the `\appendix` command somwhere in a KOMA-script document (in my case `scrreprt`) should change the behaviour of the enddot in a sectioning command: The chapters should only have an enddot if the numbering is in roman numerals (e.g. in the appendix) and otherwise should not have an enddot (according to the German scrguide).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main}

\appendix{}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

The first compilation yields headings without any dot (even in the appendix). A secon compilation, however, yields dots in both headings. Removing the corresponding .aux file and doing recompilations reproduces the results. Moreover, the KOMA-option `numbers=autoenddot` does not change the results.

Is this the expected behaviour? Why are all headings with an enddot as soon as there is the `\appendix`?

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted the information in scrguide: According to German orthography rules, if any section numbering does not contain only numbers but also characters, *all* section numberings need to have a dot at their end.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Thank you. Do you know the english orthography rules concerning this? Using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` has no effect. (In fact, I do not like the enddots in normal sections.)

Comment: No, I don't know the English rules, but as this has a special treatment in the KOMAscript guide, I would guess that no end dot is the more common way. You can easily achieve this with the documentclass option `numbers=noendperiod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can have a look into scrreprt.cls and change the definition of the chapter- or section-numbering. Probably solutions have already been published.

But to make an end to the enddots, simply do:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noendperiod, english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main}


\appendix{}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this `noendperiod` correct for an English document with an appendix?

Comment: Sorry, no clue about english documents. You'd be surprised to know what I forgot about german punctuation.